# Unable to Validate Field in Shopware Backend Form

Tags: plugins, backend, shopware

I am trying to validate a field in my ExtJs file by sending a hit to my controller.. all works fine and I get the result back.. but the problem is that I am unable to get the `me.article` in the code as it shows undefined so my logic in the controller does not return the result as expected.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

*Note*: this only happens for Shopware v.5.4.6. It works fine for Shopware 5.2.

```
Shopware.apps.Article.view.detail.Base.prototype.createLeftElements = function() {

    var me =this, articleId = null, additionalText = null;

    console.log('article', me.article);
    if (me.article instanceof Ext.data.Model && me.article.getMainDetail().first() instanceof Ext.data.Model) {
        articleId = me.article.getMainDetail().first().get('id');
        additionalText = me.article.getMainDetail().first().get('additionalText');
    }

    me.nameField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        name: 'name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        fieldLabel: me.snippets.name,
        allowBlank: false,
        enableKeyEvents:true,
        checkChangeBuffer:700,
        labelWidth: 155,
        anchor: '100%',
        vtype:'remote',
        validationUrl: '{url controller="MyController" action="check"}',
        validationRequestParam: articleId,
        validationErrorMsg: '{s name=detail/base/number_validation}Validation Message.{/s}'
    });
    // .. some code here which is irrelevant

    return [
        me.supplierCombo,
        me.nameField,
        me.mainDetailAdditionalText,
        me.numberField,
        {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            name: 'active',
            fieldLabel: me.snippets.active,
            inputValue: true,
            uncheckedValue:false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            name: 'isConfigurator',
            fieldLabel: me.snippets.configurator.fieldLabel,
            inputValue: true,
            uncheckedValue:false
        }
    ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not that deep into ExtJS, but perhaps the CSRF-protection causes this problem? Perhaps you need to whitelist your controller.

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/csrf-protection/#addition-to-backend-token-validation

Comment: nah I dont think thats an issue cause I can see my controller method being called in the network tab. Anyways, I found another way to validate through hooking the save method directly in the controller instead of calling my validation controller.